# Eliminar un pedazo de texto

Tags: bash, awk

Tengo un archivo que contiene esto:

```
...
15/Nov-01:15:41-snapd[499]:-
15/Nov-01:15:41-snapd[499]:-
15/Nov-01:15:41-CRON[3366]:-
...
```

Y quiero que TODAS las filas queden de esta manera:

```
...
15/Nov-01:15:41-snapd-
15/Nov-01:15:41-snapd-
15/Nov-01:15:41-CRON-
...
```

Como consigo esto con bash? Uso awk? o que comando?

Comment: ¿qué intentaste?

Comment: @Tacamine, puedes usar `awk`, `sed`, los builtins de la shell para lograr lo que quieras. Cuando lo intentes, comparte tus dudas. De todas maneras, el sitio y el tag "bash" te puede ser de gran utilidad para ver múltiples aproximaciones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Con AWK**

> Con awk necesitas utilizar una expresión regular como delimitador.

En este caso, he utilizado lo siguiente:

**Explicación:**

- -F"[][] utilizará como delimitador cualquier expresión entre corchetes
- |]:" <- esto es la segunda parte de la expresión regular. el | es un "or" y le añadimos como expresión "un corchete y dos puntos".

De este modo, AWK siempre eliminará los separadores al imprimir el resultado.

Por tanto, tendríamos:

**Campo 1** 15/Nov-01:15:41-snapd

**Delimitador** -> [499]

**Campo 2** VACIO

**Delimitador** -> ]:

**Campo 3** -

Así que al ejecutarlo:

```
alejandro@DESKTOP-784E0PG:/mnt/c/Users/Alejandro/prueba$ cat fichero
15/Nov-01:15:41-snapd[499]:-
15/Nov-01:15:41-snapd[499]:-
15/Nov-01:15:41-CRON[3366]:-
alejandro@DESKTOP-784E0PG:/mnt/c/Users/Alejandro/prueba$ awk -F"[][]|]:" '{print $1$3}' fichero
15/Nov-01:15:41-snapd-
15/Nov-01:15:41-snapd-
15/Nov-01:15:41-CRON-
```

**Con SED**

Para eliminar lo que hay entre los corchetes (Y los corchetes):

```
sed -e 's/\[[^][]*\]//g'
```

Para eliminar el ":" que te queda al ejecutarlo, sólo te hace falta encadenar otro Sed  en el que sustituyes la cadena ":-" por únicamente el guión.

```
alejandro@DESKTOP-784E0PG:/mnt/c/Users/Alejandro/prueba$ sed -e 's/\[[^][]*\]//g' fichero | sed -e's/:-/-/'
15/Nov-01:15:41-snapd-
15/Nov-01:15:41-snapd-
15/Nov-01:15:41-CRON-
alejandro@DESKTOP-784E0PG:/mnt/c/Users/Alejandro/prueba$
```

Espero que te haya ayudado.

La fuente original para la respuesta del SED:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/14840/153843